# Is providing an MCE in an answer now considered bad practice?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, minimal-reproducible-example

I recently provided an answer to this this [Why does this if-statement combining assignment and an equality check return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264674/why-does-this-if-statement-combining-assignment-and-an-equality-check-return-tru/56264761#56264761) which contains a (very small) compilable program. From the comments and downvotes  it seems that this is now considered  a bad thing to do. Is that really the case?

Comment: From the comments: *The answer fails to clearly explain operator precedence.*. Based on that I would say providing an MCVE is not bad practice. Providing a not useful MCVE is a down vote collector. That didn't change recently.

Comment: Answering the title: WTF? no! | Answering the question about your answer: people said MCVE to big compare to the information, some inaccuracy, and not enought explanation.

Comment: Eh.. Afaik `using namespace std` is considered a cardinal sin on SO and might've earned you a lot of the downvotes. Attributing them solely to your example might be wrong. Providing a simplified version of the problem is good only if the question warrants it imo, if the problem is stated clear enough in the question it's making the answer longer than it needs to be. And that's where opinion comes in of course, experts that vote/comment tend to need those things less than the novices that actually benefit from the answer.

Comment: You got comments from [perl] and [python] people.  Meh, everything goes a little crazy when it becomes a Hot Network Question.

Comment: @HansPassant Dismissing people's comments on an answer simply because they've participated in other topics, rather than on the merits of the actual points at hand, is not appropriate at all.  If you think they're criticism isn't valid, explain why.

Comment: 78 votes for 'I wrote/copied really bad code and want operator precedence explained yet again'.  Well, great:(

Comment: Up to 94 votes today.  Suspicious now......

Comment: @MartinJames Isn't that basically [so] HNQ's in a nutshell? It's generally more about novelty than usefulness.

Answer (score 10):

First, the concept of an MCVE isn't for answers; it's for *questions*. It helps ensure that debugging questions are both answerable without having to guess and have been debugged to some degree by the asker. So issues relating to MCVEs have nothing to do with this particular problem.

Second, my understanding of the issue people have with your answer is that it doesn't really answer the question. You say *that* the code is interpreted in a certain way, but you never explain *why* that interpretation is what gets used. And the title of the question is "***Why*** does this if-statement combining assignment and an equality check return true?" You didn't answer that. Or at least, not in a useful way.

Also, as commenters have pointed out, throwing `using namespace std` at C++ programmers is like throwing bloody meat at sharks.

Comment: "So issues relating to MCVEs have nothing to do with this particular problem."  - I'm not sure what you are saying here - are you saying that I was wrong to make the minimal effort (a couple of lines of code) I did make to make the code in my answer compilable. As for your other two paragraphs, I was not asking whether the answer was a great one - it obviously isn't. And `using namespace std;` (or any other namespace) is perfectly fine in C++ source files, as opposed to headers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: "*are you saying that I was wrong to make the minimal effort (a couple of lines of code) I did make to make the code in my answer compilable*" No. I'm saying that it is irrelevant to the issue of why your answer was poorly received. The comments and downvotes weren't there to say that compilable code is bad. They're saying *your answer* is bad.

Comment: Following comment has 19 upvotes - "Was the extra code really necessary? It seems pretty obvious that this would be the case as it would not run otherwise."

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Sure. So what? Do you believe that the downvoters did so because of that issue, or because of the other problems in your answer?

Comment: The comment is what I was asking about here!

Comment: @NeilButterworth: You asked about "the comments and downvotes". "comments" is plural, not singular. You were asking about the reception *in total*, not a specific comment.

Comment: I'd argue that MCVE's are, in some cases, extremely useful for answers. But I fully agree with answers also needing to explain the issue at hand.

Comment: The first downvotes happened at the same time as that first comment, but I'm really not interested in them - I'm interested in my headline question here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: "*I'm really not interested in them*" Then you shouldn't have brought them up in the text of your question.

Answer (score 1):

MCVE's are appropriate in answers when they're the core part of your answer (with an explanation to go with it). This is not applicable here, as the code is largely copied from the question and *the explanation* is the actual answer.

MCVE's can still be appropriate when you're copying (and/or modifying) the code from the question, but there should be a reason for this. Some good reasons are:

- Make the answer easier to follow by having the code it's talking about right there.

  This is not really relevant as there is only really one relevant line (or arguably 2), which you quoted right after this anyway.
- Clarify assumptions made *based on ambiguity* in the question.

  I assume this was the reason you included it.

  In an ideal world, this is better done by *asking for clarification* using comments before posting an answer, but let's ignore that for now.

  The objection here is many may argue the code in the question is perfectly clear and unambiguous as it stands. There could be some potential alternative interpretations based on the code you surround the posted code with, e.g. adding a `#define` to change how the code is compiled or using some other `cout`, not that the latter would directly affect the if-statement at all. But these are too unlikely to even consider as viable, especially since the question makes perfect sense by just assuming the overwhelmingly-most likely case.

So combine the (arguable) lack of a good reason for including it with the text potentially coming across as *a bit* condescending and the explanation you provided being very short and not addressing *why* it happens this way (and the common aversion to `using namespace std` around here), and the downvotes shouldn't be at all surprising.

FYI: I didn't downvote.