# What is going on here? C++ madness

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, hot-questions

I'm sorry, but I have to ask what the hell is going on here [Why does this if-statement combining assignment and an equality check return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264674/why-does-this-if-statement-combining-assignment-and-an-equality-check-return-tru) - not an interesting question, a correct but not brilliant top-voted answer, but the up-voting here seems to me to be nonsensical. Are there really so many C++ programmers that think the question and the answer (both pretty straightforward for anyone that knows a bit of c++) deserve these upvotes?

This has nothing to do with up or downvotes on my own answer - it  just seems bizarre  to me.

Comment: Yeah, the community behavior is often _bizarre_. What kind of answer do you expect? Confirmation of your observation?

Comment: @πάντα  I suppose I expect better from SO.

Comment: "Became Hot Network Question": there's your answer.

Comment: @Neil _"I suppose I expect better from SO."_ Well, what you can expect is a mediocre and broad community.

Comment: @Nicol "Became Hot Network Question" - why, how?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Who knows? Maybe someone suggested that it was an interesting question [at an off-site resource](https://isocpp.org/).

Comment: @NicolBolas It was an HNC ~8 hours before the meta post.

Comment: and er... you answered it because... what, exactly?

Comment: It is the second meta Q about the same Q. It looks like you can not accept that someone else has picked up the pot.

Comment: @Brak It's a meta issue - why are people upvoting this very average question and answer so much?

Comment: Why did you decide to answer _this very average question_ and bother to post a meta Q about [downotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385364/is-providing-an-mce-in-an-answer-now-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Brak My original  meta question was "Is providing an MCE in an answer now considered bad practice? - nothing to do with up or downvoting.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Then why is it asking why the post is getting downvotes if it's not about up or downvoting?  It seems weird to claim that the question isn't about downvotes at all when we can read the (very short) question and see it asking about the downvotes on the post.  Why make a statement so easily shown to be false?

Answer (score 15):

Not Madness, Hotness.

Based on [a secret formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions), the question was determined "too hot to handle", so it appeared in the Hot Network Question list that is shown on every Stack Exchange site in the right sidebar. From there, it attracted lots of eyes and potential voters because HNQs are "interesting".

Votes on questions that have been in that list have to be taken with a grain of salt. Lots of grains. That advice applies network-wide.

Thanks to [the dedicated work of Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) (one of the Stack Exchange Community Managers), it is now possible to determine exactly if and when a question was added to the HNQ list, because [an event is generated in the question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56264674/revisions). You used to have to just guess, or maybe remember seeing it in the list.

The question became hot because it attracted in under 4 hours after posting on 2019-05-22:

- 4 answers (2 deleted)
- 8 upvotes (2 down)
- 1 edit

The answers and edit put the question on top of the active tab, attracting more visitors. The 2 non-deleted answers got 16 (blame Nathan) and 5 upvotes on the 22nd.

If I run these numbers through the super secret Hotness formula I get an outcome of over 20% and based [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284933/158100) that is the threshold. Had you not answered it would have stayed just under (~19%) the threshold and we wouldn't have had this conversation.

Comment: If this is a thing (and I've been around here for many years - I've got the t-shirt), do we think it is a good thing?

Comment: OK, I see it is a thing - a part of the SO interface I have never looked at. But this kind of begs the question - how did the question I am referring to become "hot"?

Comment: @NeilButterworth added the calculation based on what I see in the timeline of the question and the answers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Probably not. HNQ may cause a bunch of extended discussion in comments, too chatty comment, comment complaining about downvotes, pity upvotes that comment receives, and pity upvotes for the post that contains that comment, upvotes of visitors that just find the question interesting, wasted time of some visitors, etc.

Comment: Maybe Stack Overflow questions should just not ever become HNQ's if it makes voting go into ludicrous speed :/

Answer (score 9):

I've taken notice of an interesting correlation between C++ questions getting on the HNQ list and C++ questions appearing on the [ISOCPP website](https://isocpp.org/) under their "Selected Recent C++ Questions". Not all question on ISOCPP's site get on the HNQ, so I cannot say with any certainty that this website was the cause.

However, it should be noted that this question in particular has many of the hallmarks of going viral. The premise is easily understood (here's an expression; why doesn't it do what it looks like?). The question is interesting. And the answer tells the user something easily comprehensible about the language.

So I would guess that this question got on some off-site resource somewhere, which attracted a number of viewers, which made it an HNQ, which promoted it further, etc. And because it's an easily understood question, that influenced lots of people to read and upvote it.

---

Update: Here's [another C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316291/are-there-situations-when-self-assignment-is-useful) that definitely got on ISOCPP's website, then went HNQ. In that order.